# Which is the proper use of the adverb "equally"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs, punctuation

> Because it matters to me as it does to you equally.

-In this sentence I've placed the adverb at the end of the sentence even though I'd prefer to reform the sentence, for emphasis purposes, into:

> Because it matters equally to me as it does to you.

Now I think I understand that "*equally as*" at least according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equally%20as) is kind of a different or a separate informal usage for the adverb, but their examples require to use "*as*" two times, before and after the adverb, while my suggested example here only uses one, and I prefer it this way if it's okay. So my question is, do the suggested examples or does one of them work fine, or do I have to reform it into something like:

> Because it matters as equally to me as it does to you.

or, placing "*as*" before and after the adverb *directly*:

> Because it matters to me as equally as it does to you.

In other words, which of any of those sentences would work or would not work and do you suggest others? Also a note of punctuation enhancement would be great.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not an english teacher - but a professional technical writer.

All of these usages sound strange to me...
The first two sound ok but strange, the second two sound strange and probably wrong. (Of course, if they're in a dictionary, then *I'm* wrong... But they may be dated or obsolete).

I might have said
"Because it matters to me as much as it does to you" 
or 
"Because it matters to me and you equally" or "Because it matters equally to me and you"

Using equally to make a comparison with "as" just sounds strange...
It's almost as if you're saying "Because it matters to me as it does to you," i.e. in the same way that it matters to you, it also matters to me -- and then adding equally as an extra qualifier.

OK, I just googled "as equally as" and did actually find some examples. So let me just note that it sounds strange at lest to *some* ears...

Answer (score 1):

None of your sentences sounds particularly idiomatic because it's not normal to hear *equally* used in the same sentence as *as much*. (The two are roughly equivalent, so using them together is redundant.)

If you want to keep *equally*, the following seems the best to me:

> Because it matters equally to me as much as it does to you . . .

---

However, even that seems strange. If you want to keep a derivation of *equal*, I would use something different:

> Because **my concern for it** *equals* yours.

---

But it would be more common to drop *equally* altogether and just use **as much** in this type of construction:

> Because it matters **as much** to me as it does to you.